# HQL - COUNT(IF()) giving QuerySyntaxException while compiling

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hql

I tried to get the count of AdmissionForms that has status equals to ACCEPTED but failed to do so with this query.

in Repository,

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(status='ACCEPTED',1,NULL)), COUNT(IF(status='PENDING',1,NULL)) FROM  admissionforms;
```

Exception that i got,

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 16 [SELECT COUNT(if(status = 'ACCEPTED',1,NULL)) FROM admissionforms]
```

Comment: There is no `IF()` in (standard) SQL and I'm pretty sure there is no `if` in HQL either. `AS 'ACCEPTED'` is invalid standard SQL as well. Identifiers must not be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: You need to use `CASE` with hibernate: `CASE WHEN status = 'ACCEPTED' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END`. But I would just select `COUNT(*)` where `status = 'ACCEPTED'`

Comment: @BackSlash Question updated..I posted for single answer..but what if need multiple answers for multiple status values.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name question updated

Comment: Do you want a SQL or HQL solution? In SQL it would be as simple as `select status, count(*) from admissionforms where status in ('..', ...) group by status `

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name HQL solution..

Answer (score 0):

Why not just include `WHERE` clause instead ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACCEPTED 
FROM admissionforms
WHERE status = 'ACCEPTED';
```

However, the same could be also do with conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'ACCEPTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ACCEPTED
FROM admissionforms;
```

Comment: Note: It's `AS ACCEPTED`, without quotes.